# Transformation of dynamic fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

As per the below scenario, how I can achieve this output from View.

[image: input Tables]

[image: Output]

I just try In this way

```
SELECT ',DynamicField'+ CAST(Seq AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' as ' 
+ '['+ FieldName + ']' FROM dbo.Feilds
 WHERE FieldName IS NOT null FOR XML PATH('') )
```

The above query RETURNS

```
 ,DynamicField1 as [Name],DynamicField2 as [Fname],DynamicField3 as [Lname]
 ,DynamicField4 as [Gender],DynamicField5 as [Country] 





SELECT id,Employeeid,DynamicField1 as [Name]
  ,DynamicField2 as [Fname],DynamicField3 as [Lname]
  ,DynamicField4 as [Gender],DynamicField5 as [Country] FROM TransactionDetails
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Most people prefer text instead of Images. Have you tried anything so far  and we are happy to help

Comment: Is this not just a simple select query with your column calls in the desired order?

Comment: @preeti If i understood you correctly, you will need column name as `DynamicField1 as [Name]`                 not as  `name` is that right ?

Comment: yes that's right,  i need to fetch the transaction details column as alias name as per fields table.

Comment: @preeti Easiest way could be add Square brackets to the field names

Answer (score 0):

Try This way, enclose column names in []

```
SELECT ','+'['+'DynamicField'+ CAST(Seq AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' as ' 
+ FieldName + ']' FROM dbo.Feilds
 WHERE FieldName IS NOT null FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: sorry, not work as per my requirement , i need to make join with filed table and transaction detail table. please note that i need this output from a view.

Comment: Can you include query how you are joining both tables ?

Comment: @@ven,  please go though my comment.